# How to provide a custom MessageBodyWriter for Strings in CXF

Tags: jax-rs, cxf

I have registered a custom `MessageBodyWriter<Object>` implementation in my JAX-RS application. This writer can convert various types, including strings.

The custom converter is successfully used for other types, but for strings, CXF does not consider it: It does not even call `isWriteable`. (This was different in CXF 2.x, so there seems to have been a regression in CXF 3.x.)

Stepping through the CXF 3.1.11 code, I see that in the `ProviderFactory.messageWriters` list has two entries (`StringTextProvider`, `JAXBElementTypedProvider`) before my custom provider. The first one wants to convert strings, and being first in the list, it is preferred by CXF.

How can I change this to make my provider the preferred provider for strings? E.g. is it possible to drop the `StringTextProvider`? Or is it possible to reorder the list so that my provider comes first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that subclassing `StringTextProvider` and registering that class works:

```java
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CustomeStringProvider extends StringTextProvider {

    @Override
    public void writeTo(String object, Class<?> type, Type genType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I got the idea for this approach from looking at the implementation of `ProviderFactory.MessageBodyWriterComparator`, which checks class hierarchies for ordering converters.